# Add a new text line with an existing text file by command line ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, file, shell, command-line

I have a text file which contains some words. I want to add some other words without erase previous words by linux command line. 
I use 

`echo "hello everyone" > abc.txt`
which write to the file **abc.txt** "hello everyone" (without quote) but erase previous all words. 
How can I prevent it? I just want to add "hello everyone" with previous words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` truncates a file then writes, `>>` appends. Change `>` with `>>` and you'll be golden.

Answer (score 1):

Use ">>" to append the content to end of file like:

```
echo "hello everyone" >> abc.txt
```

">" will erase the existing content and will then write hello everyone in abc.txt.